# Is there a mechanism in Python, which would allow to intercept access to an object?

Tags: python, python-internals

I want to control the variable is accessed. I tried to implement it with the help of pyjack module, but method pyjack.connect(my_str, proxyfn=my_proxyfn) throws an exception `...type '<type 'str'>' not supported`.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
>>> def on_access(obj):
...    print 'object with id=%d has been requested' % id(obj)
...
>>> s = 'some string'
>>>
>>> foo(s, handler=on_access)
>>>
>>> print s
object with id=4559856664 has been requested
some string
>>>
>>> s + '.'
object with id=4559856664 has been requested
some string.
```

Upd: It is important that the object retained its type.

In continuation of example:

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> json.dumps(s)
object with id=4559856664 has been requested
'"some string"'
```

Comment: Could you better define what does and doesn't count as an "access"?

Comment: Yes, I don't think the examples you posted make your question clear.

Comment: Looks like you just want a function wrapper. `def s(): print 'access'; return 'some string'`.

Comment: By "access" I mean any manipulation with an object, in case of string it's read "access".

Comment: it looks like `StringVar()` in `Tkinter` - but it needs `.get()` , `.set()`

Comment: I don't think this is possible for the builtin types. For user defined types it is easy: override ``__getattr__`` / ``__setattr__``

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I've updated the question. Unfortunately, the wrapper is no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this without creating some sort of wrapper class that delegates calls to the underlying "tracked" object.

Every operation on an object is eventually controlled by use of its dunders. `print`, for example, calls `__str__`, `s + '.'` first calls `__add__`, subscripting calls `__getitem__`. You'll need to define your "on access" behavior *in those functions*.

A quick basic write-up that presents the functionality in your examples could look like this:

```
class Wrap(object):

    access_str = "object with id={} has been accessed"

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    def __add__(self, v):
        print(self.access_str.format(self._obj))
        # If you want the result to be tracked 
        # return Wrap(self._obj + v)
        return self._obj + v


    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.access_str.format(self._obj))
        return repr(self._obj)

    def __str__(self):
        print(self.access_str.format(self._obj))
        return str(self._obj)
```

this is obviously *lacking* the rest of the methods required but that's something you should do if you go down this route.

Now you interact with it as you would with any string:

```
>>> s = Wrap("Hello World")
>>> print(s)
object with id=140023929394880 has been accessed
Hello World
>>> s + '.'
object with id=140023929394880 has been accessed
'Hello World.'
```

This can obviously be changed, for example in `__init__` you could force the requirement for a `name` argument which you'd then bind in the global scope via use of `globals()`.

Additionally, you could create a metaclass that does the generation of the similar dunder methods automatically for you depending on the type.

Point is, there's no built-in way to do this, you'll need to do it yourself in some tedious fashion.